# Send form output to sharepoint list

Tags: forms, azure, sharepoint, infopath, azure-web-app-service

We have a web app hosted in Azure.  We would like to add a form and send the output to a SharePoint list.  I guess my question is what/where is the connection from an azure app, function, etc., to SharePoint?  Does Azure have a streamlined process available or would this involve several routes, Form to SQL, SQL to external server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.

We can use SharePoint CSOM API to create list item because you are using web app.

According to your description, you want to send output to SharePoint List, here is a simple demo for your reference:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Create a List Item
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    /// <param name="listName"></param>
    public static void createItem(ClientContext context, string listName, FormEntity formEntity)
    {
        List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);
        context.Load(list);
        context.ExecuteQuery();
        ListItemCreationInformation itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();            

        ListItem listItem = list.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);
        listItem["Title"] = formEntity.Title;
        listItem["Name"] = formEntity.Name;
        listItem["department"] = formEntity.department;
        listItem["Age"] = formEntity.Age;
        listItem.Update();
        context.Load(listItem);
        context.ExecuteQuery();
    }

    public class FormEntity
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string department { get; set; }

        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
```

Do authentication to SharePoint, we can do as below:

```
    #region do authentication of SharePoint
    /// <summary>
    /// do authentication of SharePoint Online
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="clientContext"></param>
    /// <param name="userName"></param>
    /// <param name="password"></param>
    public static void setOnlineCredential(ClientContext clientContext,string userName,string password)
    {
        //set the user name and password
        SecureString secureString = new SecureString();
        foreach (char c in password.ToCharArray())
        {
            secureString.AppendChar(c);
        }
        clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, secureString);           
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// do authentication of SharePoint on-premise
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="clientContext"></param>
    /// <param name="userName"></param>
    /// <param name="password"></param>
    /// <param name="domain"></param>
    public static void setClientCredential(ClientContext clientContext, string userName, string password, string domain)
    {
        clientContext.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password, domain);
    }
    #endregion
```

We can download CSOM API at: [SharePoint Client Components SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038)

Comment: Thanks!  I will explore this.